# Link Genres in Advanced Custom Fields

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-fields

I am using Advanced Custom Fields. I want to link the values (eg. thriller, suspense, etc.) of Genre custom field so that when the user clicks on one of the values they will get a filtered list of posts. For eg. when they click Thriller they will get all the posts in the Thriller category.

My code so far for the ACF is as follows:

```
<!-- Entry Content Start -->
        <article <?php post_class('entry clearfix fitvids'); ?>>
            <div class="inner-post">
                <div class="cover">
                    <div class="post-image">
                        <?php
                            if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { // check if the post has a Post Thumbnail assigned to it.
                              the_post_thumbnail();
                            }
                        ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="custom-fields">
                        <?php the_meta(); ?>
                        <div class="ad">
                            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/160/600" alt="">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="the-content">
                   <?php the_content(); // This is your main post content output  ?>
                </div>

            </div><!-- /inner-post -->
        </article><!-- /entry -->
```

Is there a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

You should create a page with custom [page template](http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates). In this template you should pull posts based on the custom field passed via `$_GET` parameter.
 For example: `$movies = get_posts(array('meta_key'=>'your_custom_key', 'meta_value'=>$_GET['genre']));` 
Then you should generate appropriate links to access this page, which should link to our custom page including genre in our `$_GET` variable. For example the page's slug is `movies`. Then our links will have the following structure: `/movies/?genre=custom_field_value`.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand this. I have very very little knowledge about PHP :(

Comment: You can try to follow this [guide](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/how-to/filter-posts-by-custom-fields/).